# powerpoint vba random slide start

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PPT deck with approximatley 40 slides. The deck is comprised of 4 stories which each have 10 slides. What I want to do in Powerpoint 2010 is randomize which of the 4 stories gets told. So I think I need some kind of code that triggers behind the scenes and tells Powerpoint to either Jump to Slide 1 (story 1), Slide 11 (story 2), Slide 21 (story 3), Slide 31 (story 4).

Does anyone have some VBA they can provide that can make this happen? Powerpoint 2010. Windows 7.

Comment: Try looking at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172148(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create 4 buttons on each of these Slides ( Slide 1, 11,21,31)

Add this action on these button click.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 1 '(or11 or 21, or 31)
 End Sub
```

Note : this will work only during slideshow.